# Why do fresh mandarin oranges get very bitter when baked?

Tags: baking, oranges

Why do fresh mandarin oranges get very bitter when baked?

What compound in mandarin oranges turns bitter when heated?

Comment: are you baking rind on? and aaronunt, i think it's supposed to say ingredient in instead of of and I would rephrase it futher to say what part of the mandarine causes the bitterness.

Comment: Are we really talking about the small orange items here?

Comment: I think and hope so...because if we're talking about the people being baked I'd be bitter too! ;-)

Comment: I baked a cheesecake with fresh mandarin oranges and it was impossible to eat.
Canned mandarine oranges (sweetend) are fine.

Comment: @sarge: It was mainly a cosmetic edit on my part.  Looks like Darin fixed the rest already; either way, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white, pithy part is a source of the bitterness. Either peel more thoroughly, or trim off with a knife.

The pulp of some oranges (of the navel variety), can turn bitter when exposed to air.
http://www.preparedpantry.com/CitrusQuickGuide.htm

Comment: The link doesn't work